# changing UI dynamically in iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I was wondering if anyone knew if it's possible to change an iPhone app UI dynamically based on server calls, so for example, if user X logs in, he will see one type of a UI, and if another user logs in, another UI will appear.

Does it align with the Apple HIG (I could not find...)? I am guessing that it should be fine since theoretically I could do everything with web views, but it just doesn't sound like something apple will like.

thanks.

Comment: what type of difference you want?

Comment: theoretically present a completely different UI (different colors, different logo, font styles, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a talk on WWDC10 that is about this topic: ["Building a Server-driven User Experience"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use the new appearance API in iOS 5 framework. Here is one article which talks about it:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

Comment: thats not exactly what i am looking for...here each cell shows you a different view differently, and its ok. my question was about the overall app (so for each user, this main table view will look differently and with another logo, etc.)

Comment: azamsharp suggestion is a very good one. It describes a great technology to change the UI in one place — once you downloaded the definitions from the web.